# Way or practice to avoid multiple account subscribe from the same user/host

Tags: web-applications, language-agnostic, subscription

Scenario:

- A web application that provide a dating system for a government office.
- Users can subscribe this service and have a profile on this system.
- Users identifier is given by email or username chosen by users themselves at registration time.
- Once the user sign in, can select a date/time slot from a timetable, up to 5 appointments (other availability is useful for citizen's relatives or kids).
- The planner shows for each date/time cell, a number that indicates global availability for that time.

Problem: Users can subscribe twice or more (with different email account for example) and hold, in the worst case, all the availability in the calendar.

Is there a way to prevent (by cookies, http headers or other manner) that someone sign up multiple times?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a national document ID for subscribe to service (instead of an username or email)... using usernames or emails, there is no way (AFAIK) that your system can detect when the same person is logging multiple times using different usernames or emails, taking all appointments and producing Deny of Service...

You can still use username or emails to log to the system, but any registered person will need to have a global ID (the national docID) and such globalID it is what is used to make the "date" reservation... then, a person (globalID) cannot have more than N appointments...